# How to find the range of duplicate or same words in UITextView or from string?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I was working to find the rect of any word in textview ,where I need to find the range of the word first say as

```
NSRange textRange=[textview.text rangeofString:@"sabby"];
```

Now I am having sabby 3 times say in my textview.Now I need to get the range of the second
sabby word not the first...Then how would I do this...
And same for other words.
Because if i go with above lines of code it gives me the range of first coming word in
the textview...

Thanks n Cheers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rangeOfString:options:range:` and set the range to start after the last occurence of the string in subsequent searches.

Comment: What would I need to fill in the options...can you just give an example...thanks

Comment: Read the documentation. It's not hard, and I've provided all the info you need. This is not a "do your homework for me" site.

Comment: Yes I was going through that...thanks though....and yes thanks for your time dear....I was just asking for example not to do my stuff...thanks n cheers