# How can i highlight the repeated word from text when user selects that word in iphone?

Tags: iphone, textview, cpu-word, highlight

I have the text in text view.when i select one word from that text. If that word is repeated  3 times in textview .Then i need to highlight the word 3 times..how can i highlight that word from text view in 3 times..

Thanks in adv..

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan through the text in entire textView, then count the occurence if it is 3 or more, use NSAttributedString and highlight the selected-text and all similar texts.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572363/how-to-find-the-range-of-duplicate-or-same-words-in-uitextview-or-from-string) for getting repeated words from a text

For highlighting the range of words in textview, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940212/how-can-i-highlight-a-portion-of-the-text-of-a-uitextview)